# Is it true that $\lim_{x \to \infty} (e^{x}-P(x)) = \infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

I have already proven that $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{e^{x}}{P(x)}= \infty$. This means that $e^{x}$ grows faster than any polynomial function. Knowing this, can it be said that $\lim_{x \to \infty} (e^{x}-P(x)) = \infty$?

I believe this to be true, however I still struggle to find a way to prove it. According to the definition of divergence as x approaches infinity that I have in my notes, what I need to get to is that: "$\forall k>0, \exists x_{0} \in \mathbb{R}, \forall x\geq x_{0}, e^{x}-P(x)>k$".

Still, I seem to be having trouble in using my hypotheses correctly in order to get to this "$k<e^{x}-P(x)$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already a perfectly good answer, but here is another way to think about this: we know that for all $x\in\mathbb R$, $$e^x = \sum^\infty_{n=0} \frac{x^n}{n!}.$$ Suppose that $P(x)$ has degree $k$. From the Maclaurin expansion, we have $e^x \ge \frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!}$ for all $x > 0$. Thus $$\lim_{x\to\infty} (e^x-P(x)) \ge \lim_{x\to\infty } \left(\frac{x^{k+1}}{(k+1)!} - P(x)\right) = + \infty.$$ The last limit should be intuitive from very basic principles: it is the limit of a polynomial whose leading coefficient is positive.

Answer (score 1):

$e^{x}-P(x)=e^{x}[1-\frac  1 {e^{x}/P(x)}] \to (\infty) (1)=\infty$.

Comment: You used the product rule for limits (or whatever you call it), which is only valid if both limits exists and is finite. The first limit is not finite.

Comment: @Divide1918 How did you get that idea? If $f(x) \to  \infty$ and $g(x) \to a>0$ then $f(x)g(x) \to \infty$.